# How does mean image subtraction work?

Tags: image, machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network

To preface, I am new to the field of ML/CV, and am currently in the process of training a custom conv net using Caffe.

I am interested in mean image subtraction to achieve basic data normalization on my training images. However, I am confused as to how mean subtraction works and exactly what benefits it has.

I know that a "mean image" can be calculated from the training set, which is then subtracted from the training, validation, and testing sets to make the network less sensitive to differing background and lightening conditions.

Does this involve calculating the mean of all pixels in each image, and averaging these? Or, is the value from each pixel coordinate averaged across all images in the set (i.e. average values of pixels at location (1,1) for all images)? This may require that all images are the same size...

Also, for colored images (3-channels), is the value for each channel individually averaged?

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In deep learning, there are in fact different practices as to how to subtract the mean image.

#### Subtract mean image

The first way is to subtract mean image as @lejlot described. But there is an issue if your dataset images are not the same size. You need to make sure all dataset images are in the same size before using this method (e.g., resize original image and crop patch of same size from original image). It is used in original ResNet paper, see [reference here](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/issues/5).

#### Subtract the per-channel mean

The second way is to subtract per-channel mean from the original image, which is more popular. In this way, you do not need to resize or crop the original image. You can just calculate the per-channel mean from the training set. This is used widely in deep learning, e.g, Caffe: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306167/what-is-the-order-of-mean-values-in-caffes-train-prototxt?rq=1) and [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt#L15). Keras: [here](https://gist.github.com/flyyufelix/7e2eafb149f72f4d38dd661882c554a6#file-resnet-152_keras-py-L216). PyTorch: [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/confused-about-the-image-preprocessing-in-classification/3965). (PyTorch also divide the per-channel value by standard deviation.)

Comment: In keras's [example](https://gist.github.com/flyyufelix/7e2eafb149f72f4d38dd661882c554a6#file-resnet-152_keras-py-L216) there are 3 magic numbers which I noticed somewhere else and looked up for, I ended up here. numbers are 123.68, 116.78, 103.94, any idea where do they come from?

Comment: @schissmantics Have you checked the first link in the post? I think it is what you are looking for. It is just the mean pixel value for B, G, R.

Comment: @schissmantics these values are the mean RGB values of imagenet dataset which is used in ILSRVC challenge. You should use these values in case you load the imagenet weights into your ConvNet. If you train your own ConvNet from scratch you should calculate your dataset RGB mean values and use them instead.

Answer (score 10):

Mean image is an image where i,j,c pixel is an average of i,j,c pixels from all images. So you take a mean separately for each position and each color channel. It requires all images to have the same size of course, otherwise it is not defined. Also, it is not really about being less sensitive to different conditions - it has nothing to do with it, it is literally just to keep initial activations in a reasonable range, nothing else.

Comment: Why do we mean by saying _resaonable range_ ? if we take the [0. 255] range, we might see high activation values for pixels close to 255, but if we take, the [-128, 127] range, we might see high activations (in abs value) for pixels near -128, so under any rate,  some numerical issue might pop up